# ValidateRequest = false in MVC 2.0 .net

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want disable RequestValidation on particular view in ASP.NET MVC 2.0. So I added some necessary to view Page directive section as below:

```
<%@ Page ValidateRequest="false" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="Path" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Path>" %>
```

but still no go.

Even tried adding this in the Web.Config:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you also add `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute on the action?

Answer (score 0):

I used this method, as this is the only way I found it to work.

I replaced the invalid character with a valid one.

Ex) `strUrl = strUrl.Replace("&", "-")`

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you create a viewmodel for your object that you post back.
You can use Regular Expressions to prevend illegal characters, like < and >

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Web.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class Account
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You have to enter this")]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Too much text")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.\s]+)", ErrorMessage = "Not allowed")]
        public string Firstname { get; set; 
     }
}
```